Young adult fantasy book about a girl who accidentally kills her boyfriend and decides to attend an academy for witches or magic
I recently saw an ad on Facebook for a book about a young girl who accidentally kills her boyfriend. She decides to attend an academy for witches or magic (I can't remember which). She is forced to room with the campus mean girl, who is murdered.

Curse of Stone by Veronica Shade.


Supposedly, witches can’t kill. But Madison accidentally killed her boyfriend, and now a girl at her witch academy is dead, too.
Madison spent her life avoiding her magical abilities, but when she’s forced to use them to save her best friend from a deadly storm and accidentally kills her boyfriend as a result, she decides she needs to enroll at La Voisin School for Young Witches after all.
She knew starting a year later than her peers would come with its own struggles; she just never expected one of those struggles would be the impossible murder of a classmate. The school is spelled for safety, and witches can’t kill…so how did Giselle end up dead?
Only Giselle and her killer know, and only Madison can find out. Because now, the dead witch is haunting her. Crazy thing is, Giselle’s murder isn’t even the biggest secret this school has.
Just ask the statues.

I found it by Googling for accidentally kills boyfriend witch fantasy site:goodreads.com/book/show/. For recent books restricting a Google search to the Goodreads site is an excellent way of finding books, though it doesn't work so well for older books.
